# Help using ImageSwitcher in android

Tags: android

So In my program I used to use Imageviews in my layout to display images and had it so when a user pressed the Imageview it changes images. But i recently upgraded my project to version 8 and updated by SDK and i see now that there is a ImageSwitcher view under Transitions. I would like to replace my ImageViews with ImageSwitchers. Ive googled and searched all over but i cant seem to figure out how it works. I was wondering if anyone would be able to explain or show me an example of code on how to use it. What i want is very basic. I just want it to display an image from a bitmap and then when the user swipes left or right it changes the bitmap. I already have the bitmaps. I just cant figure out the code.

I tried using this code to start out but i couldnt get it to work with the bitmap

```
ImageSwitcher is = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
is.setImageResource(bmap);
```

I tried using this new code to turn my bitmap into a drawable but it always crashes when run. Is there something i can fix?

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bmap);
ImageSwitcher is = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
is.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setImageResource(int rsid)` takes an identifier for a resource coming from the `R class` like R.drawable.foo (being foo your bitmap).

What is bmap? An actual Bitmap instance? If so use `setImageDrawable()` instead

Regards,
JQCorreia

Comment: It is an actual bitmap instance but when i try using it like this is.setImageDrawable(newbmap) i get an error that says, "The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) in the type ImageSwitcher is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap)"

Comment: Have to wrap it around a BitmapDrawable before you do that because Bitmap is not a subclass of Drawable. Create a BitmapDrawable like `BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(newbmap)`

Comment: I tried that and whenever i try to display the image using this line of code `is.setImageDrawable(d);` it crashes when the app is launched and logcat shows this line as the problem

Comment: this line `is.setImageDrawable(d);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
is.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmap));
```